# How can I derive relative path of my executable file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path

I have converted .py file to exe using pyinstaller. My code fetches data from Excel sheet stored at specific folder and use the same to update some fields in JIRA (Webpage).

Currently I am giving full path of the excel sheet (c:\desktop\Filename.xlsx). I don't want user to input the full location of the excel file whereas just provide the file name only. For this purpose, I am thinking of keeping the executable file and excel file in same location. What I want is to fetch the base location of executable file and then append the location with file name to reach the excel file location.

Have tried **file** but it is not working? Giving an error

The below code present is written in the executable file

```
import webbrowser as wb
import os
import xlrd as x
import time
import pyautogui as p

name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
val=input("Enter worksheet name that contains Issue ID and Dev Delivery Date details:\n")
filename = os.path.join(name,'val')
my_excel=x.open_workbook(filename)
sheet = my_excel.sheet_by_index(0)
j=0
if sheet.nrows==0:
    print("\nYou have not provided any data. Kindly provide Issue ID in column A and Dev Delivery Date as a character in column B [Format:26/Sep/19]")
else:
    if j<=i:
        for i in range(sheet.nrows):
            loc="https://jira.cvent.com/browse/"+sheet.cell_value(i,0)
            wb.open_new(loc)
            time.sleep(5)
            p.moveTo(1200,700);
            time.sleep(2)
            p.press('.')
            time.sleep(2)
            p.typewrite("Dev Delivery")
            time.sleep(2)
            p.press("enter")
            p.press("backspace")
            p.typewrite(sheet.cell_value(i,1))
            p.press("enter")
            j=j+1
        else:
            os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
```

Instead of providing the full path, I want to give just the name of the file

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake here "filename = os.path.join(name,'val')" due to you put it like str, but not as attribute, try this:

```
filename = os.path.join(name,val)
```

Comment: It did not worked for me. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the relative path using Python's `__file__` variable and joining it with path to your file folder:

```
import os

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '/xlsx_folder'))
```

Then we can open the file with filename

```
my_excel = x.open_workbook(os.path.join(path, filename))
```

Comment: val=input("Enter worksheet name that contains Issue ID and Dev Delivery Date details:\n")
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
my_excel=x.open_workbook(os.path.join(path, val))